# Python decode with translation table

Tags: python, encoding

I have a text file that is encoded in the obscure "mik-bulgarian"
I am trying to convert it in utf-8.
So far I figured out I would have to read the file as bytes and somehow translate it having the translation table.
Here are some snippets of the strings I am trying to convert

> not decoded -> NAME Ј°. Џ«®ў¤Ёў
>
> HEX -> NAME \xa3\xb0. \x8f\xab\xae\xa2\xa4\xa8\xa2\r\n

```
cadFile = open(filename,"rb")
filetext = cadFile.read()

#filetest = filetext.translate(mikxtbl)

print(filetext)


 mikxtbl = { \
...
        0x80: "Cyrillic capital letter A (U+0410)",
        0x81: "Cyrillic capital letter BE (U+0411)",
        0x82: "Cyrillic capital letter VE (U+0412)",
        0x83: "Cyrillic capital letter GHE (U+0413)",
        0x84: "Cyrillic capital letter DE (U+0414)",
        0x85: "Cyrillic capital letter IE (U+0415)",
        0x86: "Cyrillic capital letter ZHE (U+0416)",
        0x87: "Cyrillic capital letter ZE (U+0417)",
...
}
```

Comment: What is your question then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to know how to translate your decoded string to utf-8:

```
tr = { 0x80: "\u0410",
       0x81: "\u0411",
       # etcetera ...
     }
"\x80\x81".translate(tr)
# result: 'АБ'
```